# Send data to ExpressJS server to render new view

Tags: javascript, jquery, express, server, client

I'm facing difficulties understanding how to send data from the client side to an ExpressJS server, to render a view based on these data.

On the client side, the user is choosing different parameters, updating the 'data-preference' attribute (basically from 0 to 6)

```
<div class="userChoice" data-preference="0">Category_1</div> 
<div class="userChoice" data-preference="0">Category_2</div>
.... Few more categories
<div class="userChoice" data-preference="0">Category_N</div>
```

I'm able to gather JSON data `{Category: preference_value}`.

However, I'm really lost (either client-side and server-side) when it comes to send these data to the ExpressJS server, and get a view based on that

---

What I tried client-side :

- jQuery : `$.get` but the data are in the URL and it seems too complicated to handle as the number of category may be important
- jQuery : `$.post` but it does not seem to take into account an `app.render` or `app.sendFile` on the server-side.

---

What I tried server-side :

- `app.post` but it does not seem to be the good way as I cannot manage to make `app.sendFile` work.
- `app.get` but I'm unable to get some data (e.g. `{Category: preference_value}`) from the client side

---

A lot of questions on StackOverFlow are related to this topic but I'm unable to find any showing how to handle both sides. Any help or link would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Server Side**

If you are posting data to a NodeJS server using ExpressJS, you'll want to install the [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) middleware. This will allow you to read posted values from `req.body`. So be sure to install this first and include it in your project.

```js
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Below the `body-parser` set-up, create an `app.post` endpoint to read the selected category and render a view based on the value.

```js
//require path module to resolve html filepath
var path = require('path');

// ...

app.post('/category', function(req, res){

    var data = req.body; // { category: <preference_value> }

    var viewName;

    switch(data.category){
      case 0:
        viewName = "ViewOne.html";
        break;
      case 1:
        viewName = "ViewTwo.html";
        break;
      case 2:
        viewName = "ViewThree.html";
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }

    var viewPath = path.join(__dirname + "/views/" + viewName);

    res.sendFile(viewPath);

})
```

You will need to require the [path](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path) module and use it to resolve the path to your HTML file. Also, be sure to place `ViewOne.html`, `ViewTwo.html` and `ViewThree.html` in the `project_root/views` directory so the `path` module can find it.

**Client Side**

To post the category data to your `/category` endpoint, you must `JSON.stringify` the category data and set `contentType: "application/json"` on the AJAX request:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    var categoryData = JSON.stringify({category: 1});

    //this will render ViewTwo

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '/category',
      data: categoryData,
      success: function(html){
         $('body').html(html); // place the html wherever you like
      },
      error: function(err){ alert('error'); },
      contentType: "application/json"
    });
  })
```

If this AJAX request is successful it will return HTML for the view retrieved in the `/category` endpoint.

So try this. Hopefully it will get you started.